# Как сделать анимацию только внутри дива?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая кнопка с анимацией, которая находится внутри div kor

```css
#kor {
    color: #343424;
    display: block;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2pe2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 21px 0 21px 20px;
    border-radius: 18px;
}
.cat{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #029e40;
    width: 185px;
    color: red;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg,#029e40,#029e40 10px,#02AA43 10px,#02AA43 20px );
    background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg,#029e40,#029e40 10px,#02AA43 10px,#02AA43 20px );
    }

.cat::before {
    animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite running pulse-bed;
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 100%;
    bottom: -870px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    left: -130px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
    top: -870px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="kor">
    <a class="cat" herf="#">добавить в корзину</a>
 </div>
```

Анимация выходит за края дива kor, не могу понять, как сделать что бы она была только по размеру дива. 
 вот фоновая картинка кнокпи 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете сделать код запускаемым?

Comment: у вас css отлично от содержимого html , сделайте пример исполняемым